# IE version <= 8: IE ignores custom css

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, styles, internet-explorer-9

I have a placeholder in the style attribute in HTML tags like this: style="custom_style: cssreplace". The purpose of this is that I can replace them with real CSS when I run JS code.

This tactic works on IE9 and IE10 but not on IE8 and earlier since then it renders the page, it just removes the "strange" custom styles.

Do you know if there is any "settings" (Doctype, etc..) in IE8 and earlier so that it doesn't ignore these tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you put it in a custom attribute `data-style="custom_style: cssreplace"`, and then add the style attribute in the JS?

Comment: Your suggestion works for me!! Thank you. Do you want to make this an answer instead so I can make this a correct answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML5 data attribute `data-style="customer_style: css_replace"`. Then have your Javascript look for this and fill in the style appropriately.